# How to kill a child process and allow parent process to continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am using node.js to monitor a website's API for commands and choose the appropriate child process based on the said command. Only one child process should be running at a time. As of now, child process 1 begins on startup of the node.js script (good). Then, when a command is heard child process 2 starts up (also good), but along with child process 1 still running in the background (not good).

How can I get child process 1 to be terminated on the start of child process 2? I am currently using `("child_process").exec;` and my code is mostly working, should I be using `("child_process").fork;` or `("child_process").spawn;` instead?

I have tried using `execFile.kill('SIGTERM');` on startup of child process 2, as well as an else/if statement without any luck. (I'll cut down on the non-essential code below).

```
const tmi = require('tmi.js');
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var execFile = require('child_process').exec;

.
.
.

(edited out)

.
.
.

// Register our event handlers (defined below)
client.on('connected', (address, port) => {
    client.action('account', 'phrase');

        execFile('/path/script.py, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
            return;
        }
    });

});

client.on('chat', (channel, user, message, self) => { 
    if (message === '!exec') {

    execFile.kill('SIGTERM'); //to try and terminate child process 1 above

        exec('/path/script.py , function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });

    }
});
```

I have worked on this issue for a while without much progress. Any and all insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
const tmi = require('tmi.js');
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var execFile = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

.
.
.

(edited out)

.
.
.

// Register our event handlers (defined below)
client.on('connected', (address, port) => {
    client.action('account', 'phrase');

        child = execFile('/path/script.py, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
            return;
        }
    });

});

client.on('chat', (channel, user, message, self) => { 
    if (message === '!exec') {

   child.kill(); //kills the child process.
}
});
```

Here is the example code. The below code starts the mongo server with child process and after 10 secs it will get killed.

```
const child = require('child_process');
const ls = child.exec('mongod --dbpath ~/Documents/myown/learning/mongo', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});

setTimeout(() => {
    ls.kill();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I tried that as well, and unfortunately, it still doesn't kill the first child process. The child process is a python script that displays gifs on an LED matrix. Would there be any reason as to why the node script couldn't kill the python script?